# Java int to python int

Tags: java, python, sockets, primitive

I have a Java server that will accept a connection from a python socket and return an int of the new port that they python script should connect to. However the 'string" that the python script gets back is blatantly unable to be converted.

Here's the python snippet:

```
s._PORT = int(s._sock.recv(1024))
print s._PORT
```

And the java side:

```
int mPort = 1592;
sock.getOutPutStream().write(IOS.getBytes(mPort++));
// IOS being a utility class that I wrote just to make byte conversions easier
```

Thanks
~Aedon

```
public static byte[] 
getBytes(Object obj) 
throws java.io.IOException 
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos= new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    oos.writeObject(obj); 
    oos.flush(); 
    oos.close(); 
    bos.close(); 
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray(); 
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Post your IOS.getBytes()

Comment: This will only work if the thing that comes out of s._sock.recv(1024) is a character string "1592". Does your IOS.getBytes(x) do such string conversion and write the four ascii characters 1,5,9,2?

Comment: So do `print s._sock.recv(1024)` and see what you're getting!

Comment: `public static byte[] getBytes(Object obj) throws java.io.IOException {
 ByteArrayOutputStream bos= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
 oos.writeObject(obj);
 oos.flush();
 oos.close();
 bos.close();
 byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
 return data;
}`

Comment: What I recieve from the server is ¼f ?sr ?java.lang.Integer?Gáñ˜üç8? ?I ?valuexr ?java.lang.Numberå¼ò??öaï?  xp  ?
9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sock.getOutPutStream().write(Integer.toString(mPort))

s._PORT = int(s._sock.recv(1024))
```

Comment: kind of worked. Now when I display it in python I can see what I'm sending. Did the conversion and got a ValueError, I expected this since I'm still getting a few special characters before the int string

Comment: Convert the string to byte[] (using for instance the IOS class in the question), and then this would work.

Comment: I did, had to, write() only takes byte[]'s.

Comment: I just did a work around, put an '@' in front of my int and just split it python side.